# What is the difference between IncomingLogCopyingNetwork and OutgoingConnections

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

What is the difference between **IncomingLogCopyingNetwork** and **OutgoingConnections**?

When I run this PS command ***Get-mailboxdatabasecopystatus –connectionstatus | fl name,outgoingconnections,incominglogcopyingnetwork*** I can see successful connections details for OutgoingConnections on a 2 node DAG but the IncomingLogCopyingNetwork has communication errors, however there are no issues with MAPI / Replication.

Thanks,

Dale

Answer (score 0):

"The IncomingLogCopyingNetwork corresponds to the database replicas. The status will show the source DAG node, the one pushing logs, and the network it is using.  You'll want to see that your MAPI network is not specified here.  The OutgoingConnections corresponds to the mounted database.  The status shows the target DAG nodes and again, the network it is using.  You do not want to see the MAPI network replicating data."

http://get-mailbox.net/monitoring-the-dag-replication-network#.VZGTSHqUzGc